# How to resolve user1 already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in Hibernate- HQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, database-connection

i am getting this exception `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException`:

```
User allnewdo_user1 already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

While i have closed session every where. in Dao Still Getting this Error

Comment: can you check the mysql settings where you define max no of connections , you can get it by `show variables like 'max_connections';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read [This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) to solve your problem by increase max_connections value in main config file.